# hidden column shows up when updating element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using a table in which I'm displaying some objects. I'm using jquery (bad, I know. But only thing I could get working) to add/remove class ng-hide from all elements with a specific ID. This results in a column being hidden and it works fine. But when any updates from the server comes and I use $scope.rows.push(object) and $scope.apply() the order of the columns gets messed up and the hidden column gets right back..

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.0" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div ng:controller="MainCtrl">

<table>
  <thead style="font-weight: bold;">
    <tr>

      <td class="text-right" data-col-id="Value1">Value1</td>
      <td class="text-right" data-col-id="Value2">Value2</td>
      <td class="text-right" data-col-id="Value3">Value3</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
      <td class="text-right" data-col-id="Value1">{{row.Value1}}</td>
      <td class="text-right" data-col-id="Value2">{{row.Value2}}</td>
      <td class="text-right" data-col-id="Value3">{{row.Value3}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>Visible Columns:</p>
<br />
<div class="cbxList" ng-repeat="column in columnsTest">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="column.checked" ng-change="columnToggled(column)"> {{column.id}}
</div>


</div>




<script>
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);




app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.columnsTest = [{
    id: 'Value1',
    checked: true
  }, {
    id: 'Value2',
    checked: true
  }, {
    id: 'Value3',
    checked: true
  }];


  $scope.rows = [{
    id: 1,
    "Value1": 911,
    "Value2": 20,
    "Value3": 20
  }, {
    id: 2,
    "Value1": 200,
    "Value2": 20,
    "Value3": 20
  }];


  $scope.columnToggled = function(column) {
    $('[data-col-id="' + column.id + '"]').each(function() {
      var element = this;
      if ($(element).hasClass('ng-hide')) {
        $(element).removeClass('ng-hide');
      } else {
        $(element).addClass('ng-hide');
      }
    });
  };



  //trigger update
  window.setInterval(function() {
    $scope.simulateUpdates($scope.rows[0]);
  }, 5000);


  $scope.simulateUpdates = function (row) {

    var newRow = 
    {
      id: 1,
      "Value1": Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1,
      "Value2": Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1,
      "Value3": Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
    }

    updateRow(newRow);
    $scope.$apply();
  }


  function updateRow(row) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.rows.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.rows[i].id === row.id) {
            $scope.rows[i] = row;
        }
    }
  }


});
```

Here is a demo of my problem in a minor scale: http://plnkr.co/edit/1tGci7qX9ZFIk69uNfIf?p=preview (uncheck one of the columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You overcomplicate things a bit: your model seems to be pretty simple actually. The key is using templates to express it properly. That's how it might look like, for example:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-right" ng-repeat="column in columnsTest"
          ng-if="column.checked" ng-bind="column.id"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
      <td ng-repeat="column in columnsTest" 
          ng-if="column.checked" ng-bind="row[column.id]"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>Visible Columns:</p>
<br />
<div class="cbxList" ng-repeat="column in columnsTest">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="column.checked">{{column.id}}
</div>
```

See? No need for that extra function: when you change the specific column `checked` attribute, it's automatically updated in all the corresponding views.

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ENR7z3PuFkKfhhAVGpUm?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you very much! My model in the demo is a bit (:)) simplified but i believe this will help!

Comment: Your code is working fine for my question. But its depending on the column names are the same as the data within each cell. How should I do it when for example the data is row.value1 but the column should be "Name"?

Comment: Attach another property - `name` or similar - to each element of `column Test` array, then use this property in `<th>` ng-bind.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed your code without using **jQuery**.

```
<table>
  <thead style="font-weight: bold;">
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="column in columnsTest" class="text-right" data-col-id="column.id" ng-show="column.checked">
        {{column.id}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
      <td class="text-right" data-col-id="Value1" ng-show="columnsTest[0].checked">{{row.Value1}}</td>
      <td class="text-right" data-col-id="Value2" ng-show="columnsTest[1].checked">{{row.Value2}}</td>
      <td class="text-right" data-col-id="Value3" ng-show="columnsTest[2].checked">{{row.Value3}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="cbxList" ng-repeat="column in columnsTest">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="column.checked">{{column.id}}
</div>
```

You don't need to bind the `ng-change` function to the input checkbox since you already assigned it the `ng-model` using two-way data-binding.

The following is the working :[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZC1HzmOwoXqnw2pg8eZk?p=preview)